# Convert newton formula to acceleration formulas

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, projectile

I am trying to understand a problem from the book *Solving Problems in Scientific Computing Using Maple and MATLAB*. The problem is about trajectories of tennis balls.
The author gives two formulas $D_L(v)$ for drag force and $M_L(v)$ for magnus force:
$$D_L(v)=C_D\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi d^2}{4}\rho v^2$$
$$M_L(v)=C_M\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi d^2}{4}\rho v^2$$
with $C_D$ and $C_M$ drag coefficient and magnus coefficient respectively.
Later he gives the trajectory vector by:
$$m\frac{d^2\vec{r}(t)}{dt^2}=-m\vec{g}-D_L\frac{\vec{v}}{v}+M_L\frac{\vec{\omega}}{\omega}\times\frac{\vec{v}}{v}.$$
So far so good. But then he derives from that the following two formulas:
$$\ddot{x}=-C_D\alpha v\dot{x}+\eta\,C_M\alpha v\dot{z}$$
$$\ddot{z}=-g-C_D\alpha v\dot{z}-\eta\,C_M\alpha v\dot{x}$$
where $v=\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{z}^2}$, $\alpha=(\rho\pi d^2)/(8m)$ and $\eta=\pm 1$ is the direction of rotation.

If I understand correctly, $\dot{x}, \dot{z}$ are the velocities and $\ddot{x}, \ddot{z}$ are the accelerations in $x$ and $z$ direction.
I do not understand how to get to these equations by plugging $D_L$ and $M_L$ in above newton formula. For example, how do I handle the cross product on the right to summarize the sum? How do I get two $\alpha$'s on the right in both equations?
And one minor thing: why $L$ in the index of $D_L$ and $M_L$? Is it for lift?

Any help is appreciated! Let me know, if I forgot an important variable or other information is missing.

Comment: Shouldn't $M_L$ depend on the rate of rotation $\omega$ also? Are you sure these are the equations given, all depending on the linear velocity $v$?

Comment: He also writes, that in this case $\omega=d/2\cdot |\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}/v|$ "...the projection of the equatorial velocity $\omega d/2$ of the spinning ball onto the velocity vector $\vec{v}$". Do we need to use this?

Comment: @Eli per our homework policy please do not give out complete solutions.

Comment: this is not a solution it is program code nothing to do with physics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $v=\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{z}^2}$ we get that $\dot{y}=0\Rightarrow y=constant$. With that on mind, the cross product is

$$\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}=\omega_y \dot{z}\hat{i}+(\omega_z \dot{x}-\omega_x \dot{z})\hat{j}-\omega_y\dot{x}\hat{k},$$

where $\hat{i} , \hat{j} , \hat{k}$ are unitary vectors in $x , y , z$ directions respectively.

Now equations of motion for each component are

$$m\ddot{x}=-C_D\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi d^2}{4}\rho v^2\frac{\dot{x}}{v}+C_M\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi d^2}{4}\rho v^2 \frac{\omega_y \dot{z}}{\omega v}$$

$$m\ddot{z}=-mg-C_D\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi d^2}{4}\rho v^2\frac{\dot{z}}{v}-C_M\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi d^2}{4}\rho v^2 \frac{\omega_y \dot{x}}{\omega v}.$$

Doing $\alpha=\frac{\rho\pi d^2}{8m}$
and $\eta=\frac{\omega_y}{\omega}$
we get

$$\ddot{x}=-\alpha C_D v\dot{x}+\eta\alpha C_M v\dot{z}$$

$$\ddot{z}=-g-\alpha C_D v\dot{z}-\eta\alpha C_M v\dot{x}.$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why $\dot{y}=0$ follows from $v=\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{z}^2}$? Also, is this not going backwards? I thought $v$ was defined after the transformation into $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{z}$ - but it could also just be a definition, that the ball is not moving in the y-direction!?

Comment: Oh wait, it follows just because there is no mention of $\dot{y}$ in the equation, so it has to be 0, I see.

Comment: I assumed that the ball is not moving in the $y$-direction from $v=\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{z}^2}$. It is true if the angular velocity of the ball is parallel to the ground and perpendicular to its velocity.

Comment: I see the cross product formula you gave now, but still have trouble getting the acceleration formulas. What even is $v^2$ in $D_L(v)$ and $D_M(v)$? Is there a way I can rewrite $\frac{\vec{\omega}}{\omega}\times\frac{\vec{v}}{v}$ to use your cross product equation?

Comment: $v$ is the relative velocity between the ball and the air, so if the atmosphere is at rest with respecto to the observer (this is a common simplification), $v$ will be the velocity of the ball and $v^2=\dot{x}^2+\dot{z}^2$. Note that the $v$ in the denominator of that cross product cancels with one coming from $D_L$ and $D_M$. When I wrote the equation for $m\ddot{x}$ I took the $x$ component of $\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}$, and the $z$ component for the $m\ddot{z}$ equation.

Comment: I do not see it. The $x$ component of $\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}$ is $\omega_y\dot{z}$. Something like this: $m\ddot{x}=-m\vec{g}-C_D\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi d^2}{4}\rho v^2\frac{\vec{v}}{v}+C_M\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi d^2}{4}\rho v^2\frac{\omega_y\dot{z}}{\omega}\times\frac{\vec{v}}{v}$? I need to somehow get a second $m$ from somewhere to substitute with $\alpha$ too, right?

Comment: The $x$ component of $\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}$ is $\omega_y \dot{z}$, that's right. However, your second expression is not. $\vec{r}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$ is a vector, as well as its second derivative $\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt}=\ddot{x}\hat{i}+\ddot{y}\hat{j}+\ddot{z}\hat{k}$. Then there are 3 expressions, one for each component, although we have already said that the one for $y$ is not relevant. When you write $m\ddot{x}$ on the left hand side, you must write just the $x$ component of each vector on the right hand side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120606/discussion-between-sebastianwilke-and-afg).